# Vector3 class in .NET framework

Tags: .net, performance, vector

I found there are two differenct implementations of a vector class in .NET framework: Microsoft.DirectX.Vector3 and Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Vector3.

Looking at member methods, they provide almost the same functionality so I am confusing.. Which of those classes are generally recommended?

My program does not need to visualize 3D objects but only need to compute CPU-intensive jobs with 3D points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from **.NET Framework 4.6** `System.Numerics.Vectors` introduces SIMD-enabled types:

- `Vector2`, `Vector3` and  `Vector4`
- Arbitrary length `Vector<T>` of type T
- `Quaternion`
- `Plane`
- `Matrix4x4` and `Matrix3x2`

(in *System.Numerics.Vectors.dll*)

If you're using DirectX or XNA you should stick to the classes they provide though.

For new projects that can use the .NET 4.6 or newer, this is the way to go.

Comment: For everyone who didn't find it in .net core, it's under System.Numerics;

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 06/2016** *This answer was originally written before .NET 4.6 was available so at that time the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll did not exist. Since then, the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll provides a strong incentive to use the types defined in the BCL*.

Depending on which framework you will be using you will need to use the corresponding structure. Otherwise they are very similar and are both value-types.

The reason there are two implementations of the same type of object in two different namespaces/assemblies is because if one would reference the other than that would create a dependency between the assemblies that otherwise is not necessary.

If you are not going to be using either DirectX or XNA then you could choose either. But in that case you should probably use the new structures defined in the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll as @JBeurer mentioned in his answer.